Seven different digits are placed in a row. The products of the first 3, middle 3 and last 3 are all equal. What is the middle digit?

Seven different digits are placed in a row. The products of the first 3, middle 3 and last 3 are all equal. What is the middle digit ?
Source: Mathigon’s 2021 calendar - puzzle # 8

heh. i didn't read "different digits" to mean that the digits have to have different values and immediately though "there are several answers to this!"

The middle digit is ...

 $2$.

Why?

 You can immediately find that you cannot use the digits $0, 5, 7$.
 If $0$ is used then some but not all products will be zero. So assume it is not used.
 If $5$ is used then some but not all products will be divisible by $5$ since there is no other digit multiple of $5$.
 The same thing goes for $7$ as for $5$.

So this means...

 the digits are $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9.$.
 Let the digits in the row be $a, b, c, d, e, f, g.$
 So the product is $a b c d e f g = 2^7 3^4.$.
 But also $a b c^2 d e^2 f g$ needs to be a perfect cube.
 The closest bigger perfect cube to $2^7 3^4$ that uses only powers of $2$ and $3$ is $2^9 3^6.$
 This means that $ c e = 2^2 3^2.$
 Since not both of them can be $6$, one has to be $4$ and the other $9.$ The order is not important since the row can be reversed and it doesn't affect the middle digit.
 Let's say $c = 4$ and $e = 9.$
 The  $a \cdot b \cdot 4 = 4 \cdot d \cdot 9$ which means $a b = 9 d.$
 Since $9$ is taken, this means both $a$ and $b$ need to be divisible by $3$, so they are $3$ and $6$ in some order.

This means the only possible value...

 for $d$ is $2$.

Now just for the fun of it here are the possible arrangements of the digits

 3642918
 3642981
 6342918
 6342981
 1892463
 1892436
 8192463
 8192436


Found a funny way to get the middle digit without solving any of the others. It assumes that a way to place the digits according to the rules exists, but is otherwise kosher:
Starting with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we can see that three identical products can only be formed by creating three identical lots of primes.
Looking at the pattern of groupings with this in mind, we can also see that we're going to need at least two of each prime we use. So 5 and 7 are out. 0 will also not work.
The prime factorisations of the rest of the digits (1,2,3,4,6,8,9) will give us 7 twos and 4 threes in total.
Since we need 3 identical lots of primes, those amounts must become divisible by 3, so we must add two each by placing 2 twos and 2 threes in the shared squares.
This gives us the composition of 9 twos and 6 threes, which makes 3 twos and 2 threes per group. The middle group contains both the shared squares, which account for two of the 2s and 3s both, so if a solution exists at all, the middle square must be the missing

 two.



 First of all, $0$ can't be there because it's the only number that makes the product in question zero. You'd need multiple zeroes. Likewise, 5 and 7 are the only digits divisible by themselves respectively. So you'd have $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9$.  $1*2*3*4*6*8*9 = 10368 = 81*128 = 2^7*3^4$  Divided by the middle digit, $10368$ must give a perfect square. That digit must be in the form of $2^{2n+1}*k^2$, so our options can be $2$ or $8$, making the square $5184 = 72^2$ or $1296 = 36^2$.  Only $3, 6$ and $9$ are divisible by $3$, meaning the former two should be shunted to a side while $9$ should be in both the opposite side and the middle three.  Then $8$ being the middle makes the middle product (and the others by extension) $72$ by ruling out $36$, creating a contradiction. Therefore, it can only be $2$.


-    Chaining where Marius got to:
    the digits are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9.
    
    Each group must be divisible by 9 (at least that one containing 9 is).
    -> The group not containing 9 must contain both 3 and 6.
    
    Only one group can contain both 3 and 6, so two groups must share 9.
    
    a b c d e f g    
        9     3 6  (permutations excluded)
    
    Remain 1 2 4 8.
    
   As a*b = d*e, the possibilities are 1 by 8 and 2 by 4 for each, giving the product 72 in each group.

e = 72 / 3 / 6 = 4

b = 72 / 9 / 4 = 2


The answer is:

 2

Here is the reason:

 Considering: $\displaystyle 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4  \times 6  \times 8 \times 9 =  1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 2^2 \times (2 \times 3) \times 2^3 \times 3^2 = 1 \times 2^7 \times 3^4 = \frac{\left( 2^3 \times 3^2 \right)^3}{2^2 \times 3^2} = \frac{\left( 2^3 \times 3^2 \right)^2\times\left( 2^3 \times 3^2 \right)}{2^2 \times 3^2} = \left( 2^3 \times 3^2 \right)^2 \times 2 $


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
